# What is the meaning of "deviation" in network scanning?

Tags: networking

e.g.

> Port is 23, Total count is 1.5k, Deviation is 1.3

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new to SO. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deviation is the change in normal behavior of the port due to port scanning. The deviation vector provides insight in suspicious port activities. More information can for example be found in ['Identifying Anomalous Port-Specific Network Behavior'](http://sei.cmu.edu/reports/10tr010.pdf) by Rhiannon Weaver.